# Не срабатывает gulp-notify в gulp-plumber. В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: node.js, вёрстка, gulp, sass, сборка

Обрабатываю ошибки в SCSS через gulp-plumber. 
Gulp-plumber срабатывает (галп не падает при ошибках), но не удается вывести уведомления в консоль.

Текущий код:

```
const gulp   = require('gulp');
sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
notify       = require("gulp-notify");
plumber      = require("gulp-plumber");
sass         = require('gulp-sass');


const onError = function (err) {
    notify({
         title: 'Gulp Task Error',
         message: 'Check the console.'
     }).write(err);
     console.log(err.toString());
     this.emit('end');
};


gulp.task('css', () => {

    gulp.src( config.src.cssEntry )
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandle: onError }) )
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'} )
        .on('error', onError))
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая конструкция работает:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./sass/*.sass')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(
            sass()
            .on('error', notify.onError({
                title: "Sass Error",
                message: "<%= error.message %>",
                sound: "Blow"
            }))
        )
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```